# Combining two awk commands in single command

Tags: unix, csv, awk

I want to combine these two command and want to invoke single command

In first command i am storing 4th column of x.csv(Separator ,) file in z.csv file.

```
awk -F, '{print $4}' x.CSV > z.csv
```

In second command, i want to find out unique first-column value of z.csv(Separator-space) file.

```
awk -F\  '{print $1}' z.csv|sort|uniq
```

I want to combine these two command in single command,How can i do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pipe the output of the first `awk` to the second `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{print $4}' x.CSV | awk -F\  '{print $1}' |sort|uniq
```

or, as Avinash Raj suggested,

```
awk -F, '{print $4}' x.CSV | awk -F\  '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

Comment: you could use , `awk -F, '{print $4}' x.CSV | awk -F\  '{print $1}' |sort -u`

Comment: You shouldn't need two `awk` processes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you are right. Sometimes I like the code simplicity at the cost of a few CPU cycles :)

Comment: I thought the whole point of the question was to avoid using two distinct awk processes!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that the content of `z.csv` is actually wanted, rather than just an artefact of the way you're currently implementing your program, then you can use:

```
awk -F, '{ print $4 > "z.csv"
           split($4, f, " ")
           f4[f[1]] = 1
         }
         END { for (i in f4) print i }' x.CSV
```

The `split` function breaks field 4 on spaces, and (associative) array `f4` records the key value.  The loop at the end prints out the distinct values, unsorted.  If you need them sorted, you can either use GNU `awk`'s built-in sort functions or (if you don't have an `awk` with built-in sort functions) write your own in `awk`, or pipe the output to `sort`.

With GNU `awk`, you can replace the `END` block with:

```
         END { asorti(f4); for (i in f4) print f4[i] }
```

If you don't want the `z.csv` file, then (a) you could have used a pipe in the first place, and (b) you can simply remove the `print $4 > "z.csv"` line.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{split($4,b," "); a[b[1]]=1} END { for( i in a) print i }' FS=, x.CSV
```

This does not sort the data, but it's not clear if you actually want it sorted or merely needed that to get unique entries.  If you do want it sorted, pipe it to `sort`.

Comment: I think you misread the question slightly; field 4 is split on space, not slash. You also don't print `$4` to `z.csv`, but that's easily fixed too.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan, indeed that is a backslash in the question.  I am assuming that storing the data in z.csv is not actually a desired side effect (similar to the sort).

Comment: It isn't clear whether `z.csv` is actually needed or just a side-effect.  Since a pipe could have been used, I incline towards "it is wanted", but that is very far from definitive.

Comment: If i dont use sort keyword than i am not able to get distinct entries,so i used sort keyword...Separator in x.csv file is ',' but 4th column of x.csv file is again separate with 'space', so i only want distinct entries in 1st column of 4th column(which is separted by space) of x.csv file.